# Visual Basic, Search box and display results in List Box

Tags: textbox, listbox

So the problem I am trying to solve requires that if the user types in a text box their user name and press enter then the files in the directory will display in the List Box. I need it to only work on the C:\Users directory. I am new to Visual Basic but not to programming so any basic advice would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Is your question about `VB6`, `VB.NET`, or a different `basic` completely? They're not  the same thing. You need to be specific in your questions here. :-) Also, what have you tried so far to figure this out yourself? We're not really a "please give me the code for this" kind of site.

Comment: I believe it is VB6. I don't have any major code yet. I just have the basic structure that visual studio give you. Like I said, I am new to Visual basic.

Comment: If you go to the Windows `Start` menu, what does it tell you that `Visual Studio` is called (the full name in the `Start` menu)? If you can't even tell what language you're using, you maybe should figure that out first and then search Google for a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
 Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")
Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
Dim dra As IO.FileInfo
```

'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each dra In diar1
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dra)
    Next

You can read more from this site, http://www.developerfusion.com/code/3681/list-files-in-a-directory/